# After intercepting a touch event, how to give it back to a child?

Tags: android, events, touch, viewgroup

I have a custom FrameLayout which overrides this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return interceptTouchEvents;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I then have a touch listener which I set as the TouchListener of this FrameLayout. At some point inside the onTouch method I'd like to forward this event to a children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use below code for dispatch touch event to view,
// Dispatch touch event to view

```
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks

Comment: if this help then please accept this answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Will do, I have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept the answer :)